# Switch buttons using Jquery

Tags: button, click

I need a help. I have this structure

```
<div class="buttons">
<p onclick="function1('param1')">button1</p>
<p onclick="function2('param2')">button2</p>
<p onclick="function3('param3')">button3</p>
</div>
```

This code works perfecty, but in addition I need add class="active" to current selected button which I can not do. The following code does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.buttons').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
return false;
}
else{
$('.buttons > p').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
}
});
})
```

Can anyone say how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in

```
<div class="buutons">
```

it should be

```
<div class="buttons">
```

Also

```
<p onclick="function3('param3')>button3</p>
```

should be

```
<p onclick="function3('param3')">button3</p>
```

JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QW3dV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

remove the onclick attribute on the p elements, it will overwrite the listener you registered in your js code, register it in the js code instead.

change you code, add "> p" in your first selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.buttons > p').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
return false;
}
else{
$('.buttons > p').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
}
});
})
```